# Подключение скриптов в отдельном шаблоне Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, blade

Вопрос не относится к какому то конкретному проекту, а в целом интересно знать кто каким образом решает этот вопрос.

Допустим, существует сайт на Laravel 5. 
У сайта, как и водится, есть `head`, `content` и `footer`. 
В футере, по правилам хорошего тона, перед закрытием тега `body` подключается собранный webpack'ом app.js в который входит к примеру jQuery.

А что к примеру делать, если мне нужно написать отдельный скрипт на том же jQuery, который будет использоваться только на одной странице сайта?

Если я напишу скрипт и вставлю его в app.js он будет грузиться на каждой странице, что не есть хорошо.

Либо в другом случае, если мне нужно передать в этот скрипт какую либо php переменную, которую я могу получить только на той отдельной странице, на которой мне нужен это скрипт.

Но если я вставлю скрипт в шаблон этой страницы. Он не будет работать. Потому что jQuery подключается в футере, и когда он подключится - мой скрипт в контенте уже попытается отработать и выдаст ошибку.

Вот как поступать в таком случае? Я вижу несколько вариантов, но все они "с душком":

1. Подключать jQuery и все другие библиотеки, которые могут понадобиться для работы других скриптов в шапке сайта. Что плохо, так как замедляет подгрузку страницы.
2. Вешать прелоадер на сайт, в процессе таймерами разруливать подключения библиотек и скриптов на сайте.

В плане web я живу немного в прошлом, может быть есть другой способ дешево и сердито подключать отдельный скрипт на странице?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В главном шаблоне сделайте что-то вроде этого:

```
<head>
    <!-- Тут Ваши скрипты -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    @stack('scripts')
</head>
```

После этого, в нужном Вам файле Вы можете подключать скрипт следующим образом:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/custom.js' }}"></script>
@endpush
```

Шаблонизатор поймёт что нужно всё из секции `scripts` засунуть в stack и мы получим кастомный скрипт в шапке сайта только там, где Вы указали.

[Статья на официальном сайте.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#stacks)

Answer (score 1):

А что если с помощью шаблонизатора? Например в head что-то типа:

```
    @if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'routeName')
        <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/yourscript.min.js') }}"></script>
    @endif
```